# Get rid of just the numers inside asterics "*" using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

What I am trying to do is to get rid of the numbers that are between asterics and keep the other numbers around. I run my regex but it erases everything between **asterics**.

```
import re
msg = """
    1 x * Build your pizza * ($ 99MXN)
    1 x * Baitz Cinnamon 16 pieces * ($ 44.50 MXN)
    1 x * Potatoes 220 g * ($ 44.50 MXN) """
re.sub(r'\*.*\*', "", msg)
```

The expected result I am looking for is:

```
  """
     1 x * Build your pizza * ($ 99MXN)
     1 x * Baitz Cinnamon pieces * ($ 44.50 MXN)
     1 x * Potatoes g * ($ 44.50 MXN)
    """
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891365/i-want-to-remove-numbers-within-asterisks-in-python-using-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `lambda` to re.sub for `repl` and filter out the digits for the substring enclosed inside asterisk:

```py
result = re.sub('\*.+\*',
                lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group(0) if not c.isdigit()),
                msg)
```

```py
print(result)
    1 x * Build your pizza * ($ 99MXN)
    1 x * Baitz Cinnamon  pieces * ($ 44.50 MXN)
    1 x * Potatoes  g * ($ 44.50 MXN)
```

You can use nested `re.sub` if you don't want to use above method (*which doesn't remove preceding/following white space characters*):

```py
result = re.sub('\*.+\*',
                lambda x: re.sub('\s*\d+\s*','',x.group(0)),
                msg)
print(result)
    1 x * Build your pizza * ($ 99MXN)
    1 x * Baitz Cinnamonpieces * ($ 44.50 MXN)
    1 x * Potatoesg * ($ 44.50 MXN)
```

Comment: Theres a duplicate post for this question on the link I added. Not sure if this is an assignment or whats going on tbh.